# SideNavBar (adding Contents)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using SharePoint Online. 
Can additional 'custom' contents be added in the left hand nav or SideNavBar? It can be simple contents such as text and images?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To appear the custom content on the left side menu of the page you can follow below steps.

**Master Page Changes**

You need to edit your master page design file (.html) from the SharePoint designer and add your HTML under `sideNavBox` div.

```
<div id="sideNavBox" role="navigation" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-forceWrap ms-noList">
    .......
    .....
    .....
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="QuickLaunchBottom"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->

    <div id="custom-content-box" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
        <p>Contact IT for help!!!</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

It appear on all pages after saving.

[image]

If you want this div for only one page. You can add this using JavaScript.

- Add a Script Editor web part to the page.
- Add following script

[image]

Comment: Thanks Venkat. The images are not showing up. I only need to add contents on one page.

Comment: You are referring the snippet image not showing?

Comment: yes, both images show 'x - enter image description here'

Comment: I can see them correct. Check these link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt36s.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXBoc.png

Comment: Thanks again. It worked.  I had to place the Script Editor at the bottom of the Main zone otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: Yes. You are right.